# why is this error shows up in data grid view column add?

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
//dgv prop
this.dgv_catg.Columns[0].HeaderText = "م"; //here is the error(Index was out of range. Must be non-negative)
this.dgv_catg.Columns[1].HeaderText = "الفئة";
this.dgv_catg.Columns[0].Width = 70;
this.dgv_catg.Columns[1].Width = 500;
DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn();
DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
column.CellTemplate = cell;
column.Width = 100;
column.HeaderText = "عدد الأصناف";
column.Name = "Items_No";
column.Visible = true;
dgv_catg.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: Are you sure the DataGridView has columns at that point? You're adding a column at the end, so are you sure the first two columns already exist in the DGV?

Comment: That error doesn't make sense. 0 is a non-negative value. It would say it was outside of the array or that the array was null if either of those things were the case. Are you sure it's 0 at that point?

Comment: That error on that line of code could only mean one thing… the grid has no columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @zgc7009 The full message is "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." It just uses the same message for both cases.